# How to use image_tab with a variable string rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using image_tag and passing a string works fine:

```
 <%= image_tag "cardBack.gif"%>
```

Outputs:

```
<img src="/assets/cardBack.gif" />
```

I am trying to do the same with a variable

```
@path = "cardBack.gif"  # On the controller
<%= image_tag "cardBack.gif"%>
```

Outputs:

```
<img src="/cardBack.gif" />
```

Is there a way to change this behavior or do I have to add the assets path on the variable value ?

Comment: I think you may have made a typo in your post/question, since both image_tags call the same thing. I tried setting an instance variable in the controller to "rails.png", and output `<%= image_tag @rails_img %>` in the view, and it worked fine.

Comment: if your path starts with a '/', it will route to the root. If not, it will route from the assets folder (examples: "/spinner.gif" will set src="/spinner -- pretty sure of that but has to be verified

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on the controller:

```
@path = "cardBack.gif"
```

Then in the view you can do this:

```
<%= image_tag @path %>
```

I hope that's what you meant?